# Modify version number defined in .c file from batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file to start doing automatic firmware builds.

Currently I have it getting the code from TFS (Team Foundation Server) and then building it (the tool is eclipse based).

However, before I build the code, I want to increment the version number, which is stored in a file version.h.  The contents of the file are:

```
/* $Header: /NG EM Controller Firmware Eclipse based/APPS/EM MAIN/version.h 2     4/25/13 10:19a user $
 */

#ifndef Version_h
#define Version_h

#define DSP_FW_VERSION 500
#define DSP_FW_ID 22
#define DESTINATION 1

#endif 

/*
 * More comments, the number increases with each check in*./
```

The line #define DSP_FW_VERSION 500  is the line I need to increment (in this case to 501).

I'm very new to batch files and am learning as I go, but this has me stumped.  I would prefer not to have to copy each line and modify the one I want, I only want to manipulate the original.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 3):

try this (*pure batch*):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "HFile=file"
SET "search=#define DSP_FW_VERSION"

FOR /f %%a IN ('^<"%HFile%" find /c /v ""') DO SET /a lines=%%a
< "%HFile%" (
FOR /l %%a IN (1,1,%lines%) DO (
     SET "line="
     SET /p "line="
     IF NOT "!line!"=="" IF NOT "!line:%search%=!"=="!line!" (
          SET /a replace=!line:%search%=!+1
          SET "line=%search% !replace!"
     )
     ECHO(!line!
))>"%HFile%.new"
MOVE /y "%HFile%.new" "%HFile%"
TYPE "%HFile%"
```

Answer (score 1):

A portable way in a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner (only one process):

```
perl -i -pe '
    BEGIN{$re = qr!^(/\*\s+\$Header:.*?version\.h\s+)(\d+)!};
    $re and s@$re@sprintf "%s%d", $1, $2+1@e
' file.h
```

Remove `-i` switch if you just want to try it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=."
SET targetfile=version.h
SET newversion=%1
IF NOT DEFINED newversion ECHO require new version number as parameter&GOTO :EOF
IF NOT EXIST "%sourcedir%\%targetfile%" ECHO %targetfile% not found&GOTO :eof
DEL "%sourcedir%\%targetfile%_before_%newversion%" >NUL
ren "%sourcedir%\%targetfile%" "%targetfile%_before_%newversion%"

(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  ' FINDSTR /n /R "$" "%sourcedir%\%targetfile%_before_%newversion%" '
  ) DO (
   SET "line=%%a"
   SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
   SET line=!line:*:=!
   IF "!line:~0,23!"=="#define DSP_FW_VERSION " SET line=!line:~0,23!%newversion%
   ECHO(!line!
   endlocal
 )
)>"%sourcedir%\%targetfile%"

FC "%sourcedir%\%targetfile%" "%sourcedir%\%targetfile%_before_%newversion%"
GOTO :EOF
```

The above batch is intended to be run with a parameter of the new version number.

It should rename the existing `version.h` to `version.h_before_newversionnumber`, and regenerate the `version.h` file, including empty line, with the one exception of replacing the target line.

The `FC` command at the end is intended merely to compare the before and after version of the file during your vigorous pre-production testing...

Answer (score 0):

```
line=`grep -E '#define DSP_FW_VERSION' version.h`
fst=$[line% *}
snd=${line##* }
nvno=`echo "${snd##* } + 1" | bc`
sed "s/$line/$fst $nvno/" version.h
```

The first line finds the line you want to modify. You may want to play defensive and make sure there is only one line found. The second line splits the beginning of the line, the third the last part into two variables. The fourth line increments your version number using 'bc'. The last one makes the change to version.h by reassembling the first part and the incremented second part. A bit ugly but it should work in bash (you need cygwin).

Answer (score 0):

Code for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk "$2 ~ /DSP_FW_VERSION/ {$3++};1" file
```

[awk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)